# Converting a generic Span<T> to a specific instantiation (e.g. Span<int>) if it actually of that type at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, memory, .net-core, casting

Consider the following C# code:

```cs
using System;

public static class C
{
    public static int[] TryGetIntArray<T>(T[] x)
    {
        if (x is int[] arr) // ok
            return arr;

        return Array.Empty<int>();
    }

    public static Span<int> TryGetIntSpan<T>(Span<T> x)
    {
        if (x is Span<int> span) // An expression of type 'Span<T>' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'Span<int>'.
            return span;

        return Span<int>.Empty;
    }
}
```

The idea is to return the argument as a particular specialization of [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0) (in this case, `Span<int>`) if the argument is actually of that type at runtime; otherwise, just return an empty span.
We can see that this approach works with an array, but fails with a span. Is there a workaround to do this with spans as well?

Comment: And it also works with ArraySegment<T>, so it is not just a value type issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can add `where T : struct`, there's a method for that:

```
public static Span<int> TryGetIntSpan<T>(Span<T> x)
    where T : struct
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, int>(x);

    return Span<int>.Empty;
}
```

Otherwise, here's another way:

```
public static Span<int> TryGetIntSpan<T>(Span<T> x)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref Unsafe.As<T, int>(ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(x)), x.Length);

    return Span<int>.Empty;
}
```

It deconstructs and reconstructs the span, as you can't just use `Unsafe.As` for this, since `Span` is a `ref` struct and therefore it's not usable as a type parameter.

The `if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))` check is optimized away by the JIT.